# List fields with a specific attribute

Tags: c#, reflection

I'm trying to list all the fields with a certain Attribute, but still not quite understanding what kind of object `GetValue()` expects.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Field, AllowMultiple = true)]
class SerializedAttribute : Attribute
{

}

class Program
{
    [Serialized] public Single AFloat = 100.0f;
    [Serialized] public Single AnotherFloat = 125.5f;
    [Serialized] public Single OnceAgain = 75.0f;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        foreach(FieldInfo field in typeof(Program).GetFields())
        {
            foreach(Attribute attr in field.GetCustomAttributes())
            {
                if (attr is SerializedAttribute)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\t" + "Variable name: " + field.Name + "\t" + "Variable value:" + field.GetValue(/*"??????????????"*/));           
                }
            }
        }

        Console.ReadKey();

    }
}
```

I tried few google searches but apperantly I'm not a very good at problem solving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GetValue` expects the instance of `Program`

```
var program = new Program();
foreach (FieldInfo field in typeof(Program).GetFields())
{
    foreach (Attribute attr in field.GetCustomAttributes())
    {
        if (attr is SerializedAttribute)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\t" + "Variable name: " + field.Name + 
                "\t" + "Variable value:" + field.GetValue(program));
        }
    }
}
```

Maybe you mean to make those properties `static`, in which case you'd pass `null` to `GetValue`. Although since you're looking for the `SerializedAttribute` that doesn't seem like the case.

Comment: typeof(Program) returns

System.ArgumentException: 'Field 'AFloat' defined on type 'ConsoleApp3.Program' is not a field on the target object which is of type 'System.RuntimeType'.'

Answer (score 1):

If you have a class:

```
public class MyClass
{
     .. fields ..
}
```

And then you do:

```
foreach (FieldInfo field in typeof( >> MyClass << ).GetFields()) ...
```

You gain access to meta data (field infos) for that type.

And then if you want to get some data from specific fields, you need to pass `MyClass` instance to `GetValue(..)` method. Because I needs a source of data.

If field is `static`, it means it is not part of `MyClass` instance, so you just pass `null` value.

So finally you should do:

```
var instance = new MyClass();

var value = field.GeValue(instance);
```